# ZFS keeps repairing the same disk when scrubbing - what does that mean?

Tags: hard-drive, zfs, smart, zfsonlinux, drive-failure

I have a ZFS pool comprised of 6 disk, arranged in 3 stripped mirrors. The server is a Supermicro X11SSM-F with a Xeon CPU, 32 GB of ECC RAM running Ubuntu 17.04. I'm using 2 Icy Dock MB154SP-B to physically host the disks, and there are 8 SATA 3 connectors on the motherboard, so the disks are being presented directly to ZFS (no RAID card in between).

This setup was running fine until very recently. Then I noticed when running `zpool status` that the last scrub had repaired some data:

```
$ sudo zpool status
  pool: cloudpool
 state: ONLINE
  scan: scrub repaired 2.98M in 4h56m with 0 errors on Sun Jul  9 05:20:16 2017
config:

    NAME                                          STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    cloudpool                                     ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-0                                    ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-ST8000VN0022-2EL112_ZA17FZXF          ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-ST8000VN0022-2EL112_ZA17H5D3          ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-1                                    ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-WDC_WD40EFRX-68WT0N0_WD-WCC4E5NFLRU3  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-ST4000VN000-2AH166_WDH0KMHT           ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-2                                    ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-WDC_WD30EFRX-68EUZN0_WD-WCC4N3EHHA2E  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-ST3000DM001-1CH166_Z1F1HL4V           ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

Intrigued, I decided to run a new scrub:

```
$ sudo zpool scrub cloudpool
... giving it a few minutes to run ...

$ sudo zpool status
  pool: cloudpool
 state: ONLINE
  scan: scrub in progress since Tue Jul 11 22:55:12 2017
    124M scanned out of 4.52T at 4.59M/s, 286h55m to go
    256K repaired, 0.00% done
config:

    NAME                                          STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    cloudpool                                     ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-0                                    ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-ST8000VN0022-2EL112_ZA17FZXF          ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-ST8000VN0022-2EL112_ZA17H5D3          ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-1                                    ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-WDC_WD40EFRX-68WT0N0_WD-WCC4E5NFLRU3  ONLINE       0     0     0  (repairing)
        ata-ST4000VN000-2AH166_WDH0KMHT           ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-2                                    ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-WDC_WD30EFRX-68EUZN0_WD-WCC4N3EHHA2E  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-ST3000DM001-1CH166_Z1F1HL4V           ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

After I let it complete, I got the following:

```
$ sudo zpool status
  pool: cloudpool
 state: ONLINE
  scan: scrub repaired 624K in 4h35m with 0 errors on Wed Jul 12 03:31:00 2017
config:

    NAME                                          STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    cloudpool                                     ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-0                                    ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-ST8000VN0022-2EL112_ZA17FZXF          ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-ST8000VN0022-2EL112_ZA17H5D3          ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-1                                    ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-WDC_WD40EFRX-68WT0N0_WD-WCC4E5NFLRU3  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-ST4000VN000-2AH166_WDH0KMHT           ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-2                                    ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-WDC_WD30EFRX-68EUZN0_WD-WCC4N3EHHA2E  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-ST3000DM001-1CH166_Z1F1HL4V           ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

I then decided to start scrubbing the pool again. After letting it run for a bit, I'm getting the following:

```
$ sudo zpool status
  pool: cloudpool
 state: ONLINE
  scan: scrub in progress since Wed Jul 12 09:55:19 2017
    941G scanned out of 4.52T at 282M/s, 3h42m to go
    112K repaired, 20.34% done
config:

    NAME                                          STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    cloudpool                                     ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-0                                    ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-ST8000VN0022-2EL112_ZA17FZXF          ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-ST8000VN0022-2EL112_ZA17H5D3          ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-1                                    ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-WDC_WD40EFRX-68WT0N0_WD-WCC4E5NFLRU3  ONLINE       0     0     0  (repairing)
        ata-ST4000VN000-2AH166_WDH0KMHT           ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-2                                    ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-WDC_WD30EFRX-68EUZN0_WD-WCC4N3EHHA2E  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-ST3000DM001-1CH166_Z1F1HL4V           ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

When looking at the SMART data for the disk, I'm not seeing anything suspicious (except perhaps `Raw_Read_Error_Rate`?):

```
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [x86_64-linux-4.10.0-26-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Western Digital Red
Device Model:     WDC WD40EFRX-68WT0N0
Serial Number:    WD-WCC4E5NFLRU3
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 262ee543f
Firmware Version: 82.00A82
User Capacity:    4,000,787,030,016 bytes [4.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2 (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Wed Jul 12 10:19:08 2017 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                                        was never started.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:                (52020) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        ( 520) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   5) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x703d) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       99
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   186   176   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       7683
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       33
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   091   091   000    Old_age   Always       -       6735
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       33
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       5
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   198   198   000    Old_age   Always       -       7500
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   110   108   000    Old_age   Always       -       42
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%        13         -
# 2  Conveyance offline  Completed without error       00%         1         -
# 3  Short offline       Completed without error       00%         1         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

I do, however, see some strange messages in the output of `dmesg`:

```
[100240.777601] ata2.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x3000000 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[100240.777608] ata2.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
[100240.777614] ata2.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[100240.777624] ata2.00: cmd 60/00:c0:c8:bc:01/01:00:00:00:00/40 tag 24 ncq dma 131072 in
                         res 41/40:00:a8:bd:01/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
[100240.777628] ata2.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[100240.777631] ata2.00: error: { UNC }
[100240.779320] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
[100240.779342] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#24 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[100240.779346] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#24 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[100240.779350] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#24 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[100240.779354] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#24 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 bc c8 00 00 01 00 00 00
[100240.779357] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 114088
[100240.779384] ata2: EH complete
[100244.165785] ata2.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x3d SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[100244.165793] ata2.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
[100244.165798] ata2.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[100244.165807] ata2.00: cmd 60/00:00:c8:be:01/01:00:00:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq dma 131072 in
                         res 41/40:00:70:bf:01/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
[100244.165811] ata2.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[100244.165814] ata2.00: error: { UNC }
[100244.167465] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
[100244.167488] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[100244.167492] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[100244.167496] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[100244.167500] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 be c8 00 00 01 00 00 00
[100244.167503] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 114544
[100244.167531] ata2: EH complete
[100248.177949] ata2.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x41c00002 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[100248.177957] ata2.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
[100248.177963] ata2.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[100248.177972] ata2.00: cmd 60/00:f0:c8:c0:01/01:00:00:00:00/40 tag 30 ncq dma 131072 in
                         res 41/40:00:b8:c1:01/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
[100248.177977] ata2.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[100248.177980] ata2.00: error: { UNC }
[100248.179638] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
[100248.179667] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#30 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[100248.179671] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#30 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[100248.179675] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#30 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[100248.179679] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#30 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 c0 c8 00 00 01 00 00 00
[100248.179682] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 115128
[100248.179705] ata2: EH complete
...
```

Grepping through `dmesg`, I see 31 such instances in the logs:

```
[100240.779357] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 114088
[100244.167503] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 114544
[100248.179682] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 115128
[100251.599649] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 115272
[100255.812020] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 115576
[100259.636088] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 115768
[100263.400169] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 116000
[100267.912099] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 116472
[100271.300223] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 116680
[100274.732989] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 117000
[100279.665331] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 118624
[100283.043738] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 118768
[100286.456260] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 119072
[100293.472354] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 7814018576
[100298.443416] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 119496
[100302.236908] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 119968
[100305.655675] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 120032
[100309.450754] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 120496
[100313.724792] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 121512
[100324.782008] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 186032
[100329.002031] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 189536
[100333.057101] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 189680
[100336.476953] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 189888
[100341.133527] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 190408
[100349.890540] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 191824
[353944.190625] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 115480
[353951.660635] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 116536
[353959.391011] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 118976
[353966.811863] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 120176
[353978.447354] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 189984
[393732.681767] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 190000
```

I'm not quite sure what to make of it:

- Why does the scrub process keep repairing data on the same disk? The amount of data repaired is going down, which would seem to indicate that data is being "durably" fixed, but why is there still data to fix when running a scrub literally hours after another scrub?
- Why am I not seeing any indications of read / write / checksum errors in `zpool status`, despite the fact that ZFS finds some data to correct on each scrub?
- Why am I seeing UREs on the disk, but nothing suspicious in the SMART report?
- What does `auto reallocate failed` mean? Has the disk already run out of replacement blocks? This is a system that has been running smoothly for the past ~ 6 months, so I would have expected problems with this disk to arise a bit sooner.

And more practically, what does that mean for this particular disk? Does it need replacement?

**Edit #1** After the latest scrub, I now get the following:

```
$ sudo zpool status
  pool: cloudpool
 state: ONLINE
  scan: scrub repaired 0 in 4h35m with 0 errors on Wed Jul 12 21:44:41 2017
config:

    NAME                                          STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    cloudpool                                     ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-0                                    ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-ST8000VN0022-2EL112_ZA17FZXF          ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-ST8000VN0022-2EL112_ZA17H5D3          ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-1                                    ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-WDC_WD40EFRX-68WT0N0_WD-WCC4E5NFLRU3  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-ST4000VN000-2AH166_WDH0KMHT           ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-2                                    ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-WDC_WD30EFRX-68EUZN0_WD-WCC4N3EHHA2E  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-ST3000DM001-1CH166_Z1F1HL4V           ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

Smartctl now says:

```
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       122
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   186   176   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       7683
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       33
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   091   091   000    Old_age   Always       -       6749
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       33
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       5
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   198   198   000    Old_age   Always       -       7507
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   114   108   000    Old_age   Always       -       38
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged
```

So... I'm good? What was that all about?

Comment: It looks that the drive had trouble reallocating the blocks it has trouble reading and ZFS saved your data integrity. You could also try to update the drive firmware as some WD Reds had dodgy fw configuration. In any case it is recommended to buy a cold spare.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity: when one read such errors as

```
[100244.167488] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[100244.167492] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[100244.167496] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[100244.167500] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 be c8 00 00 01 00 00 00
[100244.167503] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 114544
```

it means that the physical disk surface has some defect.

More specifically, the message `Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed` means that the disk encountered an unrecoverable read error. But *what is* an unrecoverable read error?

Disks read data on a sector-by-sector basis, each with a dedicated ECC. When the ECC errors surpass a specific threshold, the disk firmware automatically re-map the just read sector - transparently to the user. No kernel errors are logged in this case and the only method to observe such behavior is via SMART attributes.

However, if the sector can not be read at all (maybe because so many errors accumulated that ECC was unable to retrieve the original data) the kernel error message `Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed` is shown. If it happen on a single disk (or RAID0) system, data are really gone - you can only retrieve it from backups.

If using a RAID level with redundancy (RAID1/5/6) the, system can *repair* the bad sector by overwriting it: the disk will remap the failed sector using one of the spare ones, immediately overwriting it with the good data copy obtained by the other disks. If not spares sectors are available the kernel will log a `failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED` and you should really replace the disk as soon as possible.

The specific case of the poster shows a `mirror` setup, meaning ZFS was able to repair/remap the failing sectors. If the disk only shows an handful of bad and remapped sectors, with no significant grow, it can last for long. On the other side, if such errors are commonly found in kernel log, one has to consider replacing the failing disk as soon as possible.